# restrict access of a member to whole project so that can push only and can not pull in git and git lab

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

we've working on an **ERP** project in our company as a team and Our team has a number of members.

Each team member works on specific module that I have determined for them.

To manage codes , we're using **git** , [gitlab](https://gitlab.com) and [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) git GUI.

The challenge we are facing is **when a new member is added to team**. In fact **I do not want a new member can access to whole project codes**. But for other members who have a long history and are trusted is not any limit to access codes.

In fact I am looking for a way that each member can access only to their own codes, means that they can **push** last changes in their code but can not **pull** whole project from master for example.

Comment: I can't really understand the purpose of this. How do you want them to work on the project if they can't even pull it ?

Comment: You might want to use separate branches then and protect your master. Because I don't think it's possible to get only push access. When you want to push on a branch you didn't pull first, git will say that you can't push and you have to pull before pushing.

Comment: @AntoineThiry, my project is based on laravel and developed as separate modules. in fact each member can install a fresh laravel for himself and work on a module. after completion they should can push their code where I can merge that into master branch. in following if I changed his module , he can pull from his branch and can not pull from master.

Comment: Ok I see. I'm home in 20 min, I'll try to answer your question if it's not already done :)

Comment: @AntoineThiry, for second comment, as far as I know when we want to create a new Branch for a new Member, need to copy from another branch(that often is master that is contain whole project) , so that member will have all project codes .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll say that what you need is [**Submodules**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Basically, **don't give access to new team members to the whole project** at all.
Create a new git repository for the modules you want to develop and give them access to this repository only.

Then in your main project do this :

```
git submodule add https://github.com/yourcompany/yourSuperModule
```

This way you'll have a folder in your project directory called *yourSuperModule* with the files of your new team member's repository. And the new team member won't have any clue on what is going on in the main project.

[Here's](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/) a nice article explaining submodules and how to use them.

Comment: It's also possible to not make that person a member of the unneeded projects, so those will not even be *viewable* to the person.